# How to slice the nth column of a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, matrix, transpose, indices

I want to slice the the nth column of a list of lists.
e.g.

```
matrix = [
    ["c","b","a","c"],
    ["d","a","f","d"],
    ["g","h","i","a"]
]
```

Do i need to transpose the list and then use indices? e.g.

```
transposed = []
for i in range(len(matrix)+1):
   transposed.append([row[i] for row in matrix])
transposed[1]
>>> ['b','a','h']
```

or is there a way to use indices directly on the nested list?

I was trying something like:

```
matrix[:][1]
>>>['d','a','f','d']
```

but this does not work as I found out.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> [column[1] for column in matrix]
['b', 'a', 'h']
```

Is this what you meant?

Comment: The naming is mixed up here since the matrix in the question consists of rows. It should be `[row[1] for row in matrix]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `zip` to transpose your matrix:

```
list(zip(*matrix))[1]
```

Output: `('b', 'a', 'h')`

Comment: yes, thank you! But then I have a tuple and would need to turn it into a list again. I guess list(list(zip(*matrix))[1] would do the trick but this seems over complicated in my opinion.

Comment: @Feodor I'd go for the list comprehension, I only provided this to you as transposing was your initial approach ;)